# Keep accordion items open when clicked on another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

So I'm having this accordion component, which currently opens and close on click. But when I click on e.g. first item and it opens, when I click on second item the first close while I want to keep it open. Not sure how should I approach this.

```
const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = React.useState(props.tabIndex);

const tabs = props.tabs.map((tab) => {
    return (
        <>
            <TabContainer>
                <Tab
                    key={tab.index}
                    onClick= {() => {activTab == tab.index ? setActiveTab(-1) : setActiveTab(tab.index)})
                    className={typeof tab.content === 'string' ? '' : 'unactive-tab'}
                >
                    {tab.name}
                </Tab>
            </TabContainer>
            {tab.index === activeTab ?
                <div
                    id="content"
                    style={{ width: '100%', margin: '2rem 0' }}
                    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: tab.content as string }}
                />
                : null}
        </>
    );
});
```

Comment: You will need to add multiple states or an object with the state of each tab to check if it is opened or closed.

Comment: You want to open both for first item and second?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to separate the Accordion item in its own component based on what you want and each of them would be able to have a "opened" state.

I won't give you a full solution, but I would do something similar to this:

```
const AccordionItem = (props) => {
  // Each item has it's own state.
  const [isOpened, setIsOpened] = React.useState(false);
  return (YOUR COMPONENT);
};
```

And in your main component, you just do this:

```
const tabs = props.tabz.map((tab) => {
    return (
        <AccordionItem {...tab} /≥
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

change  `props.tabIndex` to be an array of tabs indexes rather than just 1 index.

Assuming you now send an array of indexes through props. e.g
// props.tabIndexes = [1,5,2]

```
const [activeTabs, setActiveTabs] = React.useState(props.tabIndexes);
const tabs = props.tabs.map((tab) => {
return (
    <>
        <TabContainer>
            <Tab
                key={tab.index}
                onClick= {() => {activeTabs.includes(tab.index) ? setActiveTabs(activeTabs.filter(tabIndex => tabIndex !== tab.index ) ) : setActiveTabs(activeTabs.push(tab.index)})
                className={typeof tab.content === 'string' ? '' : 'unactive-tab'}
            >
                {tab.name}
            </Tab>
        </TabContainer>
        {activeTabs.includes(tab.index) ?
            <div
                id="content"
                style={{ width: '100%', margin: '2rem 0' }}
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: tab.content as string }}
            />
            : null}
    </>
);
});
```